# How to fetch credential for azure cognitive speech services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have created a `Speech Cognitive services` on `Azure` portal and I would like to follow [this guideline](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.speech/b.cognitive-speech-services-js). somewhere in the mentioned guideline there is something like the following:

`fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/speechservices/token', { method: 'POST' })`.

My question is with which address should I replace this part of the code?
I have tried several things with no success. For instance, I tried `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken` and tried to give one of the two keys that I see under `Keys and Endpoints` as the parameter of the `post` method. But it didn't work.
I even tried using subscription key and the region, but it also didn't work. Maybe I have not used the correct syntax.

I would be grateful if anybody could help me.

Update:
Here is my updated code which still has problem with the microphone:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">

    <head>
<title>Web Chat: Cognitive Services Speech Services using JavaScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
        function createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials() {
            let expireAfter = 0;
            let lastPromise;

            return () => {
                const now = Date.now();

                if (now > expireAfter) {
                    expireAfter = now + 300000;
                    lastPromise =  fetch(
                        'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
                        { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'my_subscription-key-speech-services' } }
                    ).then(
                        res => res.json(),
                        err => {
                            expireAfter = 0;

                            return Promise.reject(err);
                        }
                    );
                }

                return lastPromise;
            };
        }

        const fetchSpeechServicesCredentials = createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials();

        (async function () {

            const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
                { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer My_direct_line_secret_key1' } });
            const { token } = await res.json();

            const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                credentials: fetchSpeechServicesCredentials
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                {
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                    webSpeechPonyfillFactory
                },
                document.getElementById('webchat')
            );

            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
        })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For simplicity, I copy the code which worked after the long discussion with @Hury Shen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Web Chat: Cognitive Services Speech Services using JavaScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>


       

        (async function () {

            const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer my-directline-secret-key' } });
            const { token } = await res.json();

            let authorizationToken;
            const tokenRes = await fetch(
                'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken',
                { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'my-cognitive-services-subscription-key' } }
            );

            if (tokenRes.status === 200) {
                region = 'westeurope', 
                authorizationToken = await tokenRes.text()
            } else {
                return (new Error('error!'))
            }

            const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                authorizationToken: authorizationToken,
                region: region 
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
            }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
        })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Best,
Hanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use one of the keys under "Keys and Endpoints" in the header of your post request but not as the parameter of your post request. Below is a request sample for your reference:

```
const tokenRes = await fetch(
  'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
  { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'yourCognitiveServicesSubscriptionKey' } }
);

if (tokenRes.status === 200) {
  region = 'westus',
  authorizationToken = await tokenRes.text()
} else {
  return (new Error('error!'))
}
```

You can also test it in postman. Below screenshot is my test, I put the key in "header" of the post request but not in "Params".
[image]

======================**Update**=====================

According to some test, I think you should use the endpoint address as below:

If do it in one app service, you should use:

`https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token`

The js code should be:

```
const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
const { token } = await res.json();
```

If just for test(expose the key in page), you should use:

`https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate`

The js code should be:

```
const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer your_secret' }});
const { token } = await res.json();
```

======================**Update 2**=====================

You can modify your code according to the code below:

```
let authorizationToken;
const tokenRes = await fetch(
  'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
  { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'yourCognitiveServicesSubscriptionKey' } }
);

if (tokenRes.status === 200) {
  authorizationToken = await tokenRes.text()
} else {
  return (new Error('error!'))
}

const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory( {
  authorizationToken: authorizationToken
} );

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine: directLine,
  webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
}, document.getElementById('webchat') );
```

Comment: Thanks @Hury Shen. It helped me and I am one step forward now :), but I get another error on a later stage in my js code. I think my address for the direct line is also not correct. Could you please tell me where I can find its related end point. For the direct line, I see the keys by clicking on the edit button. But when I use the messaging endpoint there as the address, it doesn't work. What's the correct end point?

Comment: I also tried to follow the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-webchat-client?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
But unfortunately, still no success.

Comment: Hi @user13578 Could you please have a try with `const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer your_secret' }});
        const { token } = await res.json();`. I'm not sure.

Comment: @user13578 Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. It also helped and I'm again one step forward. Before that, the microphone symbol was not shown, but now it is shown, but it doesn't work. I can chat with my bot, it is correctly connected on the text base. But when clicking on microphone I see this message in the web console: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: web-speech-cognitive-services: Either "authorizationToken" or "subscriptionKey" must be provided."

Comment: @user13578 You should provide `authorizationToken` in your code like `const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
  authorizationToken: authorizationToken
});`.

Comment: @user13578 The `authorizationToken` is in the first code block of my answer.

Comment: @I updated my post with my code. Could you please take a look at that?

Comment: @user13578 Please provide `authorizationToken` instead of `credentials` in your `createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory` code

Comment: @user13578 The `authorizationToken` comes from the first code block of my answer. In your code, it may be `authorizationToken: lastPromise.text()`

Comment: @user13578 Please refer to my "Update 2".

Comment: I just tried your second update, but it also didn't work. Did I have to replace the whole js part with the new one? I mean, don't I need to give the credential of the direct line to my code any more? If it is so and I have understood it correctly, I would say it doesn't work, but I am wondering how I could expect it to work?

Comment: @user13578 As you mentioned the error message is `Either "authorizationToken" or "subscriptionKey" must be provided`. So I think you need to add `authorizationToken` in your code. What's the error message now ?

Comment: @user13578 May I know how did you try with my "Update 2" code ? Could you please provide your latest code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220077/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-user13578).